# Insert an image to pdf files

Tags: python, image, pdf

I am trying to insert an image to multiple pdfs.

I started by doing it in a single pdf.

But I am getting an AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'InsertImage'

Could you please help me?

Below you can find the code.

```
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("example.pdf")
rect = fitz.Rect(0,0,100,100)
for Page in doc:
    Page.insertImage(rect, filename = "image1.jpg")
doc.save("new.pdf")
```

Comment: The question has been changed. There is no error any more in the question. The error was an incorrect typing of "insertImage".

Answer (score 3):

For me works writing:

```py
page.insert_image(rect, stream=img)
```

Comment: Hello for some reason my comment was deleted..This solved the problem. Thanks!